# Paste register before the column selection in VIM

Tags: vim

1) Considering VIM, I have a yanked text `PRE` using `y`.

2) I select first column of characters (`t`s) in the following file.

```
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
text6
```

3) I want to put the text `PRE` stored in **register** before the selected characters as follows.

```
PREtext1
PREtext2
PREtext3
PREtext4
PREtext5
PREtext6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 1st solution :

`:%s/^/\=@name of register/`

- 2nd solution:

`:g/^text\d/ put!=@name of register | normal! gJ`

- 3rd solution :

<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>name of register</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd>